# Airflow backfill new task added to dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Lets say today is 2017-10-20. I have an existing dag which is successful till today. I need to add a task with a start_date of 2017-10-01. How to make the scheduler trigger task from 2017-10-01 to 2017-10-20 automatically ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the backfill command line tool.

```
airflow backfill your_dag_id -s 2017-10-01 -e 2017-10-20 -t task_name_regex
```

This is assuming there is already a DAG run for dates beginning from 2017-10-01. If that's not the case, make sure the DAG's start date is 2017-10-01 or earlier and that catchup is enabled.

Comment: i tried this on a dummy-`DAG` (solely for testing) but it gave me `AirflowException: BackfillJob is deadlocked`. See complete stacktrace [here](https://textuploader.com/1dmb7). I'm on `Python 3.7.3`, `Airflow 1.10.3`, `LocalExecutor`

Comment: UPDATE: fixing date-range (`-s` and `-e` params) in above command resolved the error. Now on CLI it says `Backfill done. Exiting.`. But when I peek into `task_instances` table in `Airflow`'s meta-db, I don't see any new backfill runs for the said task

Comment: You can add `--reset_dagruns ` to the command for you to manually backfill even if the DAG has run previously on the backfill days

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind executing the whole DAG again, you can remove it from the Web UI and it will appear again with status `Off`. If you enable it again, it will run from the beginning, including the new tasks.